# How to query a table partitioned on a column in AWS Athena that uses Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

If I have created a table like this in AWS Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table (
         `timestamp` BIGINT,
         `id` STRING,
)PARTITIONED BY (
        date_column STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat' LOCATION 's3://bucket/key' TBLPROPERTIES ( 'parquet.compress'='SNAPPY', 'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 'classification'='parquet')
```

And after adding data, date_column looks like this:

```
date_column
date=2018102300
date=2018091500 //(so Sept 15, 2018)
```

I want to get data only for the month of September but unable to frame the correct query:

So far I have this which throws date format error:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where date_parse(date_column, 'date=%Y%m%d') >= date_parse('date=2018090100', 'date=%Y%m%d') and date_parse(date_column, 'date=%Y%m%d') < date_parse('date=2018100100', 'date=%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Why do you store "date=2018102300" instead of "2018102300"?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters which you are passing to function date_parse() are incorrect.It should be in below format to fetch correct timestamp format

```
select date_parse('2018091500', '%Y%m%d%H') will fetch you 2018-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

You can rewrite your query to fetch results for September

```
select * from  table where date_parse(date_column, '%Y%m%d%H') between date '2018-09-01' and date '2018-09-30'
```